# passing value of input text to another input text with another page, jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

this is my page 1

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="House Number" id="hhouseid" name="hhouseid" />

<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" type="submit" id="house" name="house">Save and Proceed</button>
```

this is my jquery

```
$('#house').click(function() {

    var hhouseid = $('#hhouseid').val();

    var datastring = '&hhouseid=' + hhouseid;

    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'query/save.php',
        data: datastring,
        cache:true,
        success:function(html){
            alert('Records Sucessfuly Recorded');
            window.location = 'add_member.php';
            $('#houseid').val(hhouseid);    
        }
    });
});
```

this is my page 2

```
<input class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="House Number" id="houseid" name="houseid" />
```

i want to pass the value of hhouseid in my page 1 to houseid in my page 2. . i have this code but it doest not work. any help accepted tnx :D

Comment: javascript doesn't maintain state across pages. Use a url param and set the value using php. Or store the data in a session since it seems to be member related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not have `$('#houseid').val()` available once you change location with `window.location = 'add_member.php';`

Perhaps you will need to carry the variable to `add_member.php` via url:

```
window.location = 'add_member.php?hhouseid=' + hhouseid;
```

Comment: still it will not sent the values to another page. .

Comment: make sure you get the value using `$hhouseid = $_GET['hhouseid'];` in `add_member.php`

Answer (score 0):

In the php code

Add

```
$hhouseid = $_GET['hhouseid'];
```

Change

```
$('#houseid').val(hhouseid);
```

To

```
$hhouseid
```